# How do I obtain contraband in Star Wars Commander?

Tags: star-wars-commander

So, I built a storage container for this "contraband" stuff.

How do I obtain some? I noticed I can steal it, as it shows up on the victory/defeat screen. But how can I generate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can steal it from other players, or you can build a contraband trade port when your headquarters is lv7.  The trade port will generate "x" amount of contraband every hour.